Console in browser show two different values for a field at the same time depending on the foldedness
I print out my object to the console. It clearly shows that the value of field locked is true. However, unfolding it to view closer details, shows the value of false. At the same time!
I perfectly understand it's not black magic, so the value only can be one of those at the same time. It means that the rendition of the value to the console somehow gets affected. Restarting the browser, the computer and switching between Edge and Chrome give no change. It also happens at another computer.
I suspect that it's something with the applications wire-up that confuses the browser. However, due to the size of the application, I can't post a minimal, reproducible example. I'll have to break it down piece by piece until I find the issue (which will be outside the scope of this question).
What I wonder is a good way to poke around it. What could I test and how can I inspect deeper (than the usual consoling out etc.).
The code says precisely this.
console.log('vm', this.vm.rows);
for (let i = 0; i < this.vm.rows.length; i++)
  console.log('forrish', this.vm.rows[i]);
this.vm.rows.forEach(a => console.log('each', a));

I seem to get correct printout on the first line and while looping but not when I iterate. (The same weirdness occur when I use .map(...) too. It's like iteration causes something. But it makes no sense to me...


Click on the i icon. Chrome shows a popover message that explains logged variables value can be stale.


Does it mean that the expanded version is more up to date?

that also seems gets outdated. here if i go ahead and change value to true on next line the expanded version still shows false. When taking this screenshot. I had assigned false before expanding. Since it was first expansion it took the up to date false value at the time. Basically both the log and its expansion don't get updated ever after being first logged/expaned.

Got ya. It's +1 and accepted answer. Regrettably, I'm stuck just as before. There's something in my application changing the state of the row and I simply can't see what... Thanks, mate.

Nevermind if you already knew this trick - If the object on which you have this locked property has a associated class then you can define a setter for this property and add a breakpoint inside that setter. this will help you see the callstack when something tries to change this property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

I'm too stressed with the project so I didn't get to diving into that. Instead, I took the pragmatic solution. Instead of binding the state of the checky by [(ngModel)="row.locked"] I simply rely on (click)="onClick($event,row)" and set it explicitly in the mething. I have no idea why it won't work with the ngModel (since it does work for the change of styling of that row) but at least the quacker behaves now. Still... feels like the computer won. At at least tied... :)
